# Android gallery of LinearLayouts

Tags: android, button, gallery, android-linearlayout

I'm using Gallery widget to create gallery of LinearLayouts, each of them containing a button. The problem is that while scrolling or clicking LinearLayout that button gets "pressed" state. How do I prevent it? I want it to react only to direct button clicks.

Thanks

// Edit: attached code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="260dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dip">

  <!-- some other things here -->

  <Button style="@style/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Just testing" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Could you post your layout code?  You could try setting the LinearLayouts to android:clickable="false"

Comment: I've included the code. android:clickable didn't help, but thanks anyway

Comment: This is likely intended behavior.  If it really bothers you, you could try using a GestureListener to make the GalleryView behave how you want it to.

Comment: It's definitely behaviour intended by android developers, otherwise it wouldn't work that way. What I'm asking is how can I disable it.

Comment: Make all of your buttons clickable="false" unless you detect a MotionEvent that you want it to react to?

Comment: I think focusable="false" must help

Comment: Even setting both clickable="false" and focusable="false" doesn't help. The button still gets the background from selector android:state_pressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just found out the same question has been asked here: [Gallery/AdapterView Child Drawable State](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858220/gallery-adapterview-child-drawable-state)

Overriding setPressed did the trick.